# failed to determine cluster membership from join-block: failed to validate config metadata of ordering config: consenter localhost:9443

Tags: linux, hyperledger-fabric, http-status-code-400, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-orderer

Help me please! I generate need tls certificate and keys. Then I modify configtx.yaml file and create genesis block successfully. Then I modify orderer.yaml and start orderer successfully. I try to execute this command:

```
./bin/osnadmin channel join --channelID channel1  --config-block ./channel-artifacts/genesis_block.pb -o localhost:9443 --ca-file $OSN_TLS_CA_ROOT_CERT --client-cert $ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT --client-key $ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY
```

But every time I receive this error:

```
Status: 400
{
        "error": "cannot join: failed to determine cluster membership from join-block: failed to validate config metadata of ordering config: consenter localhost:9443 has invalid certificate: verifying tls client cert with serial number {serial number}: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
}
```